# Quicksort function with vector object C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I'm trying to convert this function to use a vector object instead of an integer array.
The vector object looks like this:

```
std::vector<Heltal *> htal;
```

The Heltal class contains a private integer named heltal.

How would I sort the htal vector using the function below?

```
void Array::Sort(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int low = first;
    int high = last;
    int x = a[(first+last)/2];
    do {
        while(a[low] < x) {
            low++;
        }
        while(a[high] > x) {
            high--;
        }
        if(low<=high) {
            std::swap(a[low],a[high]);
            low++;
            high--;
        }
    } while(low <= high);
    if(first < high)
        Array::Sort(a,first,high);
    if(low < last)
        Array::Sort(a,low,last);
}
```

Comment: What have you come up with?

Comment: Stop using pointers already. What's the point?

Comment: have you tried? there should be no change. Also you dont need the `Array::` in `Array::Sort(a,low,last);`

Comment: Yes I've tried with replacing the int a[] parameter with the htal parameter but I doubt storing lots of Heltal objects in the function is the best way to do it.

Comment: Kerrek SB feel free to recommend a better method if you know one.

Comment: I'm too tired, is there something special about this sort?  Why not just use std::sort?

Comment: Mark: I've tried std::sort but it doesn't seem to do anything. The vector looked just the same as it did before after sorting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution is to ditch your custom sort and use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) from `<algorithm>`. This will pretty much be guaranteed to be faster and more optimal in almost every case. Then you just have:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::vector<Heltal *> htal;
...
// sort by pointer value
std::sort(htal.begin(), htal.end());
```

If you want to sort by object value rather than pointer value, either use `std::vector<Heltal>` instead of `std::vector<Heltal *>` (which is almost certainly what you should be doing anyway), or pass a comparison function to std::sort.

Example using C++11 lambda for this:

```
std::sort(htal.begin(), htal.end(), [](Heltal *a, Heltal *b) { return *a < *b; });
```

Comment: I believe he wants to sort by an int value inside of the object.

Comment: That is correct Mark, the vector object can be printed like this (the only way I know of at least) htal[0][0].

Comment: @Kraffs if you have operator< defined for your class, then you can use std::sort just fine, you don't need to get at any internal members. Alternately, you can make the comparison function you pass to std::sort a friend of the class.

Comment: Ha, ha, sorry wjl with that little tidbit of information, looks like your solution correct.  Now I just feel like we are doing @Kraffs homework though.

Comment: @Mark perhaps you're right! But if it's quicksort homework the professor probably wont like just using std::sort ... =)

Comment: @wjl, I think the homework is in using comparison operators :)